# Firebase CurrentUser Null, how to keep user logged in all activities?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a blog app, the registration works great, when successful,  a new intent where there's a userProfileActivity starts, I added in this activity a button to write a post (opens a new activity with editTexts to fill ), the problem is: the currentUser is null on all the activities except the registration one, does this have to do with calling the function finish() after opening a new activity?
can you please explain to me how to keep the user logged in?

```
/*after successful registration,the profile activity starts, here's what inside the oncreate methode*/

fabAddClasseP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent addPostIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, addPostActivity.class);

                startActivity(addPostIntent);


        }
    });
```

```
/* the addPostActivity*/
/* declaration*/
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
/*a reference to the post*/
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dataPost");
/*a refernce to the user/author of post*/
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dataUser");

//then below on the onCreate methode, i make sure all edit texts are filled, 

buttonSavePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//if  all filds are not empty
String PostId = mDatabase.child("PostId").push().getKey();



 //getting the current user id if not null
String userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();





                       writeNewDataPost( userId, PostId, titlePost, contentPost);


    private void writeNewDataPost(String user_id,String post_id, String title, String content) {

        DataPost dataP = new DataPost(title,  content);

            mDatabase.child(Post_id).setValue(dataP);
/*adding a 

node to the current post "author, and setting its value to the current logged in user*/    
    mDatabase.child(post_id).child("author").setValue(user_id);

               }
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that proves that the user is not logged in when you think they should be.

Comment: When you register a new user in your app, the state is always saved (or should be)

Comment: Please add the code that proves that the user is not logged.

Comment: @AlexMamo the app crashes when i click on add post button

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry if my code is messy, i'm a newbie

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: @AlexMamo that the current user is null, it shows in the logcat, i used an if statement

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you for pointing out to check again the error, after following "Eldho P James" answer, the crash was due to a progress bar i had commented it's findById(), Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current userID into your other activities use this code

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

String userId =currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
```

Comment: This is a waste of server-side resources. I don't think that's the correct solution.